# How to convert a string looking like a list to list of floats?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have this list:

```
s = '[ 0.00889175 -0.04808848  0.06218296 0.06312469 -0.00700571\n -0.08287739]'
```

it contains a `'\n'` character, I want to convert it to a list of `float` like this:

```
l = [0.00889175, -0.04808848, 0.06218296, 0.06312469, -0.00700571, -0.08287739]
```

I tried this code, which is close to what I want:

```
l = [x.replace('\n','').strip(' []') for x in s.split(',')]
```

but it still keeps quotes that I didn't manage to remove (i tried `str.replace("'","")` but it didn't work), this is what I get:

```
['0.00889175 -0.04808848  0.06218296 0.06312469 -0.00700571 -0.08287739']
```

Comment: Why are you splitting on `,`? there is not a single `,` in your input. Also, there is not a single `,` in your output. Are you working with actual lists or with numpy arrays?

Comment: This: `s=[ 0.00889175 -0.04808848  0.06218296 0.06312469 -0.00700571 -0.08287739]` is not a list. It might be a numpy array representation. Lists look like `s=[ 0.00889175, -0.04808848,  0.06218296, 0.06312469, -0.00700571, -0.08287739]` . Please [edit] and clarify what you need.

Comment: @ATidedHumour I took the liberty to edit your question to be a bit clearer, please refine it even more if you feel like it.

Comment: [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Where do you get your input data from?

Comment: @DeepSpace that is because I have a list of list of these separated by ','

Comment: @Gerogy these are bottleneck tensor values (tensorflow).                               
PS: Why did I get a downvote on my question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were quite close. This will work:

```
s = '[ 0.00889175 -0.04808848  0.06218296 0.06312469 -0.00700571\n -0.08287739]'

l = [float(n) for n in s.strip("[]").split()]

print(l)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [0.00889175, -0.04808848, 0.06218296, 0.06312469, -0.00700571, -0.08287739]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

First thing needs to cleared that if you are keeping the str then there will be quotes unless you typecast each of element of your str by splitting it.

Following is my solution to your problem:

```
s='[ 0.00889175 -0.04808848  0.06218296 0.06312469 -0.00700571\n -0.08287739]'

#removing newline \n
new_str = s.replace('\n', '')

#stripping the brackets and extra space
new_str = new_str.strip(' []')

#splitting elements into a list
list_of_floats = new_str.split()

#typecasting from str to float
for _i, element in enumerate(list_of_floats):
    list_of_floats[_i] = float(element)

print(list_of_floats)

#output
#[0.00889175, -0.04808848, 0.06218296, 0.06312469, -0.00700571, -0.08287739]
```